# How to sort out this form navigation

Tags: php, forms

I have this form tag below where the form submits to itself which I want to happen everytime the form is submitted UNTIL the $sessionMinus (which is a number) equals the same number as ($_SESSION['initial_count']) then I want the form to submit to the session_marks2.php. How Can I get that to work?

Below is my current  tag:

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
```

Below is the if statement for where $sessionMinus equals $_SESSION['initial_count']:

```
if ($sessionMinus = $_SESSION['initial_count'])
```

Comment: "=" is an assignment operator. Use "==" or "===" to compare values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
if ($sessionMinus = $_SESSION['initial_count'])
```

is always true and should be

```
if ($sessionMinus === $_SESSION['initial_count'])
```

your code should be something like

```
$action = ($sessionMinus === $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? "session_marks2.php" : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

and then

```
action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>"
```

Comment: Hi, I have done what you have stated but what happens is that if I have 2 sessions(exams), when I complete the first exam, it should submit form to itself which it was doing but now it just takes me to an error page. This is where the two numbers don't match so it should submit form to itself, not to an error page? If numbers do match then it should submit to session_marks2.php but instead that is going to an error page as well